# Sustituir valor null de un array

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
let array = [[444, 500], [444, null], [444, 200],[444, null]],
```

Necesito sustituir el null, por el ultimo numero de array[1] encontrado.

```
let arrayEsperado =  [[444, 500], [444, 500], [444, 200],[444,200]],
```

Comment: Que haz intentado? Si no nos muestras tus avances es mas complicado poder ayudarte

Comment: array.forEach((item) => {

            if (item[1] === null) {

              item.splice(1, 1, '2');
            }
        });

Comment: En este caso, con el metodo splice estoy sustituyendo el null, por el numero dos.

Comment: En lo que estoy atorada es como guardar en una variable el ultimo numero encontrado

Comment: tengo una duda antes de responder... que llegaría a pasar si primer  array[1] fuera null??? con que numero se reeemplazaria???

Comment: se quedaria en null

Comment: Eso deja un vació grande, si el primero es null y el segundo también es null el según no cambiaría... y lo mismo con el 3ro, y con el 4to, el 5to, 6to, 7mo... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te pongo este ejemplo que puede servirte. Como tu variable es un array que contiene arrays entonces la idea será iterar y evaluar la posicion 1 de los subarrays:

Si no es null entonces que se almacene en una variable auxiliar...

Y si lo es entonces almacenar en esa posición el dato almacenado es esa misma variable auxiliar

```js
let array = [[444, 500], [444, null], [444, 200], [444, null]];

console.log(array);

var aux = 0;
array.forEach(( subArray )=>{
    for (let indice = 0; indice < subArray.length; indice++) {
        if(indice === 1){
            if(subArray[1] != null)
                aux = subArray[1];
            else
                subArray[1] = aux;
        
        }
        
    }
});

console.log(array);
```

Este ejemplo corre sin ningun problema y cumple con lo que pides...

Pero como te plantee en los comentarios, hay un vacio grande en el caso de que la posicion 1 del primer subarray sea null, y la posicion 1 del segundo tambien lo sea entonces este no podra asumir un valor... y lo mismo con el 3ro, 4to, 5to, ... etc...

Espero se entienda este vacio que menciono

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, si en el caso de la que la primera posición del 1 del segundo tambien lo sea entonces este no podra asumir un valor, por lo que quedaría en 0.  En este caso se podrían sustituir los valores 0 por un null.

Comment: Por algo parecido también  asigne la variable auxiliar como 0.... Si la respuesta se adecua a tu pregunta por favor dala como respondida para que otras personas que pudieran tener la misma duda puedan encontrarla mas fácilmente

Comment: Listo, muchas Gracias